# Buckwheat raw pizza base

Tags: raw, buckwheat

This question is for a raw pizza base using sprouted buckwheat.

I love having something crunchy, savoury carb-rich to eat. This is why I am trying to get my sprouted buckwheat pizza base to a point where it's *actually* yummy.

I am failing. I mean, it's "OK" with lots of topping, raw tomato sauce, raw cheese, olives, capsicum, etc. But... in all honesty, the base *in itself* is just not very good, mainly because of the bitterish starchy-ish taste of buckwheat.

I am using:

- 1 cup buckwheat
- 1 cup linseeds
- 1/2 cup sundried tomatoes
- 1 cup of dates
- 1 cup of water
- Salt

What can I blend the taste of raw buckwheat with, so that it "works"? I thought the dates would help, but...

Comment: Try sprouting a different grain? Barley or wheat or rye...?

Comment: What's the problem with the base? Is it texture, flavor, not holding together?

Comment: Flavour. Starchy, borderline bitter, with a strong aftertaste

Comment: Why sprout it?  Grind the buckwheat to flower (or buy buckwheat flower) and all your problems will be gone...

Comment: I am eating it raw. Phytate, the main phosphorus storage in plants, is resistant to digestive enzymes and blocks the absorption of essential vitamins and minerals such as Zinc, Magnesium and Calcium. It goes away by sprouting...

Answer (score 1):

Let me approach the question in two parts 1) you want to flavor the buckwheat 2) you need a binder (currently you're using dates). 
My suggestion 1* / use avocado and mash some dried spices (basil, oregano, etc) into it. The avocado is going to be the oil. Do not add any other oil.  2* / try de-seeded zucchini in your buckwheat blend - the idea is to experiment with **mushy** plants with low water content (thus you need to remove the seeds of the zucchini in this example).
These are theories as I'm not raw but still hope the direction helps :)

Comment: Linseeds also work as a binder in raw recipes. It's basicaly _the_ binder. I am experimenting, and more dates is working well. Going to add one avocado, zucchini and some italian herbs, let's see what happens!

Comment: Best of luck! Put on some sun-dried tomatoes while you're at it maybe :)